# How to build Boost using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2013

When building boost using the newly released Visual Studio 2013, the following error occurs:

Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

I am building boost using bjam via the following command:

bjam %BJAM_PROCESSORS% --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete msvc --stagedir=stage stage

I must build boost using the command prompt, I am unable to download a prebuilt version of boost.

Thanks.

Comment: What's boost version? Do you run `bootstrap`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upcoming boost release (1.55.0, scheduled for early November) should support VS2013 (also scheduled for release in early November)

[ And yes, I know that VS2013 was "released for the web" already, but its' official release date is Nov 13. Silly marketing. ]

Answer (score 8):

You must get the latest release version from their SVN server, then use `toolset=msvc-12.0`.

Comment: I entered toolset=msvc-13.0 did i ruin everything?